# Fix Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

Pls help me to parse the page! I dont mind what to do

PHP code:

```
[{"DATE_REG":"04.04.2014","NAME_WDAY":"\u041f`\u044f\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0446\u044f","NAME_PAIR":"3 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430","TIME_PAIR":"11:25-12:45""},{"DATE_REG":"04.04.2014","NAME_WDAY":"\u041f`\u044f\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0446\u044f","NAME_PAIR":"6 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430","TIME_PAIR":"16:35-17:55""}]
```

My code:

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             name2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             para2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.para);
             aud2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aud);

} 
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    return json;
                }
                 @Override
                 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                     pDialog.dismiss();
                     try {
                            // Getting JSON Array
                         for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
                            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                            String NAME_FIO = c.getString(prepod);
                            String ABBR_DISC = c.getString(para);
                            String NAME_AUD = c.getString(audit);
                            //Set JSON Data in TextView
                            name2.setText(NAME_FIO);
                            para2.setText(ABBR_DISC);
                            aud2.setText(NAME_AUD);
                         }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is returning an array and you are attempting to parse a JSONObject from it. Change your AsyncTask and parser return types to JSONArray and use that in your onPostExecute loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

First you JSON is **INVALID** in your response one **"** is extra for every array element.

your JSON might like below..

```
[
    {
        "DATE_REG": "04.04.2014",
        "NAME_WDAY": "П`ятниця",
        "NAME_PAIR": "3 пара",
        "TIME_PAIR": "11:25-12:45"
    },
    {
        "DATE_REG": "04.04.2014",
        "NAME_WDAY": "П`ятниця",
        "NAME_PAIR": "6пара",
        "TIME_PAIR": "16: 35-17: 55"
    }
]
```

It's **JSONArray** not **JSONObject** try to get like below.

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
```

and

```
           @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }
```

then

```
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {
                        // Getting JSON Array
                     for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                        String NAME_FIO = c.getString(prepod);
                        String ABBR_DISC = c.getString(para);
                        String NAME_AUD = c.getString(audit);
                        //Set JSON Data in TextView
                        name2.setText(NAME_FIO);
                        para2.setText(ABBR_DISC);
                        aud2.setText(NAME_AUD);
                     }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```